# How to grep the required string from the result of alternatives --display java using start and ends with?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I wanted to fetch two outputs from the `alternatives --display java` list
, one is `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-1.8-oracle-x64/bin/java` and the other is `/usr/java/jdk-11.0.17/bin/java` I use the below command

```
alternatives --display java | grep -o '^/usr.*bin/java\>'
```

and I get output

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-1.8-oracle-x64/bin/java
/usr/java/jdk-11.0.17/bin/java
```

To be specific, this server has jdk 8 and jdk 11 installed. What additional regex can be added to the above command to get the output seperately ?
I need help with the above command to get the single output as

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-1.8-oracle-x64/bin/java
```

when trying to fetch jdk-1.8
and

```
/usr/java/jdk-11.0.17/bin/java
```

when trying to fetch jdk-11.0.17

eg when i run `alternatives --display java | grep -o '^/usr.*1[.]8*bin/java\>'` , the output should be `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-1.8-oracle-x64/bin/java` and when i run `alternatives --display java | grep -o '^/usr.*11[.]0[.]17*bin/java\>'` , the output should be `/usr/java/jdk-11.0.17/bin/java` . Unfortunately , I get no result when i run the command in the example

Comment: do you know the actual strings you're searching for (ie, `jdk-1.8` or `jdk-11.0.17`) or are you trying to search on just the major version (ie, `8` or `11`)?

Comment: @markp-fuso , the output should be as mentioned '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-1.8-oracle-x64/bin/java' , complete path . eg when i run alternatives --display java | grep -o '^/usr.*1[.]8*bin/java\>' , the output should be /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-1.8-oracle-x64/bin/java and when  i run alternatives --display java | grep -o '^/usr.*11[.]0[.]17*bin/java\>' , the output should be /usr/java/jdk-11.0.17/bin/java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From OP's comment the following do not work:

```
grep -o '^/usr.*1[.]8*bin/java\>'
                    ^^^^^
grep -o '^/usr.*11[.]0[.]17*bin/java\>'
                          ^^^^^
```

The problem here is the `8*bin` and `7*bin` which says to match on 0 or more of the characters `8` or `7` followed by the string `bin`; of course, the strings `.bin`, `.8bin`, `.8888bin`, `.1bin`, `.17bin` and `.17777bin` do not occur in the input so no output is generated.

Try applying the `*` to the single character wildcard character (`.`), as is done at the front of the pattern (`user.*`); so, slight modification to OP's current code:

```
grep -o '^/usr.*1[.]8.*bin/java\>'
                     ^
grep -o '^/usr.*11[.]0[.]17.*bin/java\>'
                           ^
```